# Could Molly Weasley create a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

Molly Weasley is the only character I can remember who's killed someone (Bellatrix) and remains alive at the end of the HP novels, save for Harry killing Voldemort.

**Can she learn the magical procedure and if she has means to do it (e.g. to protect her family forever), create her own Horcrux?**

Comment: Yes, the second question should be separate.

Comment: @malachi1990 - In this instance, editing it out seems appropriate.

Comment: why would a hocrux protect the family?

Comment: @Skooba - So she could remain alive indefinitely, protecting her family.

Comment: If you're just speaking about the ability, maybe? But if you're talking about her desire, then I think not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say **probably not.**

So technically speaking, what makes the creation of Horcruxes possible is the act of tearing your own soul. (killing is just the way you tear your soul)

However, in the same book when we see Snape's memory of his conversation with Dumbledore, Dumbledore makes the following comment after asking Snape to kill him:

> "You [Severus] alone know whether it will harm your soul to help an
>   old man avoid pain and humiliation" (Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Scholastic hardcover edition page 683)

While granting the standard disclaimer about whether Dumbledore was lying or not, it does imply that one can kill without tearing one's soul. That being said, the conditions under which one might not tear their soul are not clearly defined, but at least from what Dumbledore says, it seems the motivation behind killing plays a part in it.

In this case, the question becomes "Would Molly tear her soul when killing Bellatrix?" If so, then yes, she could make a Horcrux, given the knowledge and desire (though I would point out that given what we know of Molly, she **wouldn't** make a Horcrux, even if she had the ability to do so).

If the answer is no, then she couldn't make one, but the question becomes why wouldn't her soul be torn? In Molly's case, her killing of Bellatrix was motivated by love for Ginny. And given that love (especially a mother's love) is portrayed as being a powerful protective magic under certain circumstances that may protect Molly's soul from being torn.

Answer (score 7):

Pottermore indicates that merely killing someone isn't sufficient. You need to commit an act of **murder**. Not only that, but the implication is that some degree of cold-blooded premeditation is also required to truly fracture the soul.

> They [Horcruxes] can only be created **after committing murder**
>
> <sup><sub>[Pottermore - The Horcruxes](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/the-horcruxes)</sub></sup>

and

> **Tom Riddle:** *"But how do you do it?"*
>
> **Horace Slughorn:** ***"By an act of evil** — the supreme act of evil. By committing murder.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

---

Additionally, JKR has indicated that act of dark magic needs to be conducted in order to prepare the vessel for the remnant piece of soul

> **The receptacle is prepared by dark magic to become the receptacle of a
> fragmented piece of soul and that that piece of soul deliberately
> detached from the Master Soul** to act as a future safeguard or anchor
> to life and to safeguard against death.
>
> <sup><sub>[PotterCast Interviews J.K. Rowling, part one." PotterCast #130, 17 December 2007.](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1217-pottercast-anelli.html)</sub></sup>

Since Molly Weasley **neither committed premeditated murder** (her actions are best considered an act of self-defence), nor is there any evidence of her having spent any time learning to commit **acts of powerful dark wizardry**, the simple fact is that she isn't equipped to create a Horcrux.

Comment: well, she did WANT to kill bellatrix

Comment: @Himarm - The fact that it's specifically called out as "***murder***" on multiple occasions would strongly imply that *pre-meditation* is a key element of the process. Simply killing someone isn't enough. You need to do it with a grave degree of malice aforethought.

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is "No." We don't know the exact requirements to create a Horcrux, but it is far more involved than just killing someone.

Creating a Horcrux requires a great deal of magical power and knowledge, and likely is time-sensitive.  We've never seen anyone create a Horcrux outside of the time they actually committed a murder, which would lead me to believe that the fracturing of the soul required is something that is temporary.  Given a bit of time, the soul will naturally mend, which would prevent creating the Horcrux.

So there's two reasons she can't: she doesn't know how and she didn't do it soon enough after she killed Bellatrix.

Other reasons, such as morality, legality, practicality, etc could be examined...but there's really no need.  Molly Weasley **did not** and **would not** create a Horcrux.  Given that, 'could have' is a rather pointless question.

Comment: I like this answer, and have given my +1, but in this world I don't think it would be right to say that a murderer's soul would mend. More, I think, the chance to make use of the damage has been missed. I imagine it as like if you tore open a pillow and the feathers scattered. Immediately you might be able to put them to some other use - but certainly not shortly afterwards.

Comment: I believe that canonically speaking, there's only one way to mend the damage to the soul -- remorse. Without that, can it be demonstrated from canon that the damage is temporary?

Comment: @malachi1990 I think that was for joining together the pieces of an already made horcrux, if I remember correctly. I think the answer is implying a soul getting damaged by murder (which will eventually heal) without creating a horcrux

Answer (score 0):

> Can she learn the magical procedure...

Most likely not

Hogwarts probably has the most extensive collection of books on ancient powerful magic, which were all taken away by Dumbledore finally becoming only available to Hermione. She does not seem to have shared the information from those books to anyone other than Harry and Ron. The only other place I can think of which would have similar books is the Ministry, but I doubt Molly would have access to those either. It is unlikely that she could or would have learned the magical procedure by the time she attacked Bellatrix

> ...and if she has means to do it (e.g. to protect her family forever),
>   create her own Horcrux?

Most likely not as well
After the war she probably went to her old lifestyle of a housewife which would not involve fatal duels with dark wizards, and I doubt she would give the required time and effort to collecting information on how to make horcruxes and learn the procedure, let alone actually make an attempt at creating one.